# Comparing time in angular 5

Tags: typescript, angular5

I am trying to compare current time with certain given time. For e.g I need to check if the current time is in between 8 pm to 8 am then how do i do using angular 5? Specially, how do i compare the constant time i.e 8pm and 8 am.

I tried in this way but still not able to specify am and pm:

```
let cutOffStartTime = new Date();
cutOffStartTime.setHours(10);
cutOffStartTime.setMinutes(15);

let cutOffEndTime = new Date();
cutOffEndTime.setHours(10);
cutOffEndTime.setMinutes(18);

if(this._datePipe.transform(new Date(),'hh:mm a','GMT-5','en-US') >= this._datePipe.transform(cutOffStartTime,'hh:mm a','GMT-5','en-US') &&
this._datePipe.transform(new Date(),'hh:mm a','GMT-5','en-US') <= this._datePipe.transform(cutOffEndTime,'hh:mm a','GMT-5','en-US')){
  sometext
 }
```

Comment: You can use moment js. https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/diffing/

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there, just use `setHours(22)` for 10 pm, or as the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours#Syntax) puts it:

> **Parameters**
>
> **hoursValue**: Ideally, an integer between 0 and 23, representing the hour. If a value greater than 23 is provided, the datetime will be incremented by the extra hours.